# Parse SNMP MIB files in Java

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmp4j

I need to parse a MIB file for OIDs and alarm types. However, I can't use [mibble](http://www.mibble.org/) as it is GPL licensed. Is there any other tool or sample code I can use to parse MIB files in Java?

Answer (score 2):

Before dismissing Mibble totally, perhaps worth mentioning there are non-GPL options with it. Quoting http://www.mibble.org/doc/faq/license/#Q12

> Q12: Ok, GPL doesn't work for me. Now what do I do?
>
> The GNU GPL licensed version of Mibble may not work for everyone.
>   There are a number of ways to approach this:
>
> - Purchase a Commercial License - As an alternative to using the GNU GPL, a non-exclusive commercial license for Mibble can be purchased.
> - Use an Older Version - Versions 1.2 to 2.3 of Mibble were licensed under GNU GPL but with an exception allowing linking with non-GPL
>     code, effectively making the license LGPL. All these versions contain
>     bugs and are unmaintained, but they may still work for you.
> - Relicense to GNU GPL - Any code licensed under the GNU GPL may freely use the Mibble library. By relicensing your software (or only
>     the applications dependant on Mibble) under GNU GPL you may continue
>     using the latest version of Mibble.

Comment: Great response! I may also be worth pointing out that if the answerer is able to use a commercial closed-source alternative, the WebNMS java API is available for a fee. I may be smart to make a pricing comparison. I've used their API for parsing MIBs and it is servicable and reasonably robust, and their support is good.
https://www.webnms.com/snmp/